# is CUDA 11 with RTX 3080 support tensorflow and keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I attached RTX 3080 to my computer. but when training on keras 2.3.1 and tensorflow 1.15, I got some error "failed to run cuBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED, did not mem zero GPU location . . . check failed:start_event !=nullptr && stop_event != nullptr" I think the problem is that recently released rtx 3080 and CUDA 11 is not yet support the keras 2.xx and tensorflow 1.xx. is this right? And what make that problem?

Comment: **...about general computing hardware and software.** This question is more likely to get an answer on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 3):

At the moment of writing this, currently Nvidia 30xx series only fully support CUDA version 11.x, see https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/can-rtx-3080-support-cuda-10-1/155849/2

Tensorflow 1.15 wasn't fully supported on CUDA since version 10.1 and newer, for probably similar reason as described in the link above. Unfortunately TensorFlow version 1.x is no longer supported or maintained, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43629#issuecomment-700709796

TensorFlow 2.4 is your best bet with an Ampere GPU. It has now a stable release, and it has official support for CUDA 11.0, see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

As TensorFlow 1.x is never going to be updated or maintained by TensorFlow team, I would strongly suggest moving to TensorFlow 2.x, excluding personal preferences, it's better in almost every way and has [tf.compat module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat) for backwards compatibility with TensorFlow 1.x code, if rewriting you code base is not an option. However, even that module is no longer maintained, really showing that version 1.x is dead, see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/versions#what_is_covered

However, if you're dead set on using TensorFlow 1.15, you might have a chance with Nvidia Tensorflow, which apparently has support for version 1.15 on Ampere GPUs, see https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-tensorflow-on-a100-gpus/

Comment: Is there a Docker image for TF 2.4?

Comment: There is indeed, here's a link to Docker hub TensorFlow images filtered by version 2.4 https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=2.4

Comment: run "docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:2.4.0-gpu" for base stable GPU image or "docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:2.4.0" for CPU image.

Comment: Well I'm getting strange errors when trying to run my RNN (something with the GRU layer) with this image. I'm not getting it with the other images by TensorFlow and Nvidia NGC that use 2.3. TensorFlow stability is so awful :(

Comment: Wasn‘t aware of the pre-built NGC Docker images for TF from NVIDIA. System limitations require TF 2.3, but the RTX 3090 requires CUDA 11. This did not work with the pre-built TF Docker images from TensorFlow, but it worked with the NGC image from NVIDA. Thanks.